# sed/perl one liner for parsing csv file and calculating averages

Tags: perl, sed

I have a requirement of a one liner in Sed which can do an inplace edit to a CSV file having the below data. I need to identify unique process id's having the lowest start time. And in the process find average of the process.

Example in below data, i would need the output as 
9110089, 12:59:00, calculated (4.1916 + 38.5992 + 13.1219)/3 , calculated (6.702 + 50.619 + 8.49)/3 
9199888, 01:50:00, calculated (3.7563 + 16.859)/2, calculated (1.956 + 41.5076)/2 
(Note: Spaces entered between columns, just for illustration)

**DATA**

```
process    start    avg1   avg2
9110089, 14:59:00, 4.1916, 6.702
9110089, 12:59:00, 38.5992, 50.619
9110089, 19:50:00, 13.1219, 8.49
9199888, 10:50:00, 3.7563,  1.956
9199888, 01:50:00, 16.859,  41.5076
299889,  00:39:00, 14.947,  5.4813
299889,  00:39:00, 3.67,    3.17004
```

Please provide me some pointers, really bad at one liners.

Comment: Sed can't do arithmetic with capture groups.  Perl etc could.

Answer (score 1):

The solution using **datamash** + **sort** + **cut** pipeline:

```
datamash -ft, -g 1 mean 3 mean 4 < <(tail -n +2 yourfile | sort -t, -k1,2) | cut -d, -f1,2,5,6
```

The output:

```
299889,00:39:00,9.3085,4.32567
9110089,12:59:00,18.637566666667,21.937
9199888,01:50:00,10.30765,21.7318
```

---

Additional ***gawk*** approach:

```
awk -F, 'NR<8{ a[$1]["avg1"]+=$3; a[$1]["avg2"]+=$4; c[$1]++; if(!($1 in t)) t[$1]=$2 }
     END{ for(i in a) print i,t[i],a[i]["avg1"]/c[i],a[i]["avg2"]/c[i] }' OFS=',' \
     <(sort -t, -k1,2 yourfile)
```

The output:

```
299889,00:39:00,9.3085,4.32567
9110089,12:59:00,18.6376,21.937
9199888,01:50:00,10.3077,21.7318
```

Comment: Thanks RomanPerekhrest for the one liner. This is really useful. But i need to run this on systems without the datamash installation. Couple of extra lines won't matter, but i need this in pure sed or perl. Thanks!

Comment: @ran1n, added awk solution